# How to make a cUrl request without receiving the response?

Tags: php, curl

Normally I Post data when I initiate cURL.  And I wait for the response, parse it, etc...

I want to simply post data, and not wait for any response.
In other words, can I send data to a Url, via cURL, and close my connection immediately? (not waiting for any response, or even to see if the url exists)

It's not a normal thing to ask, but I'm asking anyway.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $MyUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_send); 
curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the only way to *not actually receive the whole response* from the remote server is by using `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. For example:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $MyUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_send); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'do_nothing');
curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

function do_nothing($curl, $input) {
    return 0; // aborts transfer with an error
}
```

**Important notes**

1. Be aware that this will generate a warning, as the transfer will be aborted.
2. Make sure that you do not set the value of `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, as this will interfere with the write callback.

Answer (score 7):

You could do this through the `curl_multi_*` functions that are designed to execute multiple simultaneous requests - just fire off one request and don't bother asking for the response.

Not sure what the implications are in terms of what will happen if the script exits and curl is still running.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $MyUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_send); 
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);
$running = 'idc';
curl_multi_exec($mh,$running); // asynchronous
// don't bother with the usual cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but via command-line I suppose you could use the '--max-time' option - "Maximum  time  in  seconds that you allow the whole operation to take."

I had to do something quick and dirty and didn't want to have to re-program code or wait for a response, so found the --max-time option in the curl manual

curl --max-time 1 URL